# How to get the height of a terrain in three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

How to get the height and maybe the surface normal of a terrain (plain) at a given x, z point?
I've searched a lot, but I haven't found anything about this.

As far as I know I should use rays, but I don't really know, how to use them.

Comment: If you're generating the terrain using a height map texture you could just get the color of the pixel instead.

Comment: I don't use heightmap texture. I generate the heights with a function.

Comment: Well, maybe you can query that function then, or you could draw in a canvas with that function and check the pixels.